# Another exception was thrown: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://10.0.2.2:8000/My_pharmacy/myph/public/images/651d25d2137d9-.jpg

Tags: flutter, image, xampp

I had uploaded image to my local database successfully but i cant display it on screen when data base return name image with `.jpg`  format but Flutter say not found.
Here is where I stored my image in the database:

[image: this is pictures]

This is my code:
[image: this is the problem]

I am trying to display it on the screen and find the correct path. Can you help me?

Comment: can you share the image url here.

Comment: http://10.0.2.2:8000/My_pharmacy/myph/public/images/651d25d2137d9-.jpg

Comment: I think it's your local server address. it can't be resolved from the outer source